# How do I send option to pstricks when it's loaded inside a pst-all \RequirePackage?

Tags: pstricks

I am trying to use pdflatex --shell-escape to compile a .tex file. But I need to use pstricks with the [pdf] option.

inside the .sty file it includes inside pst-all
\RequirePackage{pst-all,pst-blur,multido}

How do I send pstricks the [pdf] option?

Of course you know this is the call inside pst-all.sty

...

```
%% Public License, as described in lppl.txt in the base LaTeX distribution.
%% Either version 1.0 or, at your option, any later version.
%%
\ProvidesPackage{pst-all}[2008/01/01 the main pstricks tools]
\RequirePackage{pstricks}  % important
% this loads the xcolor package and pstricks in the right order
% and does some modification to the color handling. Look at the
% doc for the options.
```

....

Answer (score 2):

Before `\documentclass` you can say

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{options}{package}
```

or you can just say

```
\RequirePackage[options]{package}
```

But unless the package is being loaded by your document class, it is simpler to just say

```
\usepackage[options]{package}
```

earlier in the preamble i.e. load `pstricks` before `pst-all`.

```
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-all}
```

Since `pst-all` is not passing options to `pstricks`, you should not get complaints about conflicting options etc.

Answer (score 1):

or use

```
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-all}
```

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler:

```
\documentclass[…, pdf]{…}    
\usepackage{pst-all}
```

The document class proposes every option it doesn't know to all subsequently loaded packages, and similarly, pst-all will propose the `pdf` option to every package it loads, among which `pstricks`.

Comment: Ok thanks, the pdf option to the document worked. Now it's giving me odd behaviour but that's not the problem...

Comment: @daemondave: Do you mean an odd behaviour with respect to what happens in the latex -> dvips -> pstopdf cycle?